# SEO Meta Data Tag In Header of WordPress Theme

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress theme for movie website. I want to add metadata tag for keywords but when i add this in WP theme Header its work for all my posts mean show these keywords for all posts that's why google not indexing all my posts. Is there any solution to fix this because I only want this for my homepage and without any plugin.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="hollywood movies download, action movies, HD Movies">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (is_home()) : ?>
    <meta name="keywords" content="hollywood movies download, action movies, HD Movies">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Open your theme's header.php file.

2.Find the  section of the file.

3.Add the following code within the  section, before the closing  tag:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) : ?>
<meta name="keywords" content="hollywood movies download, action movies, HD 
Movies">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The keywords tag no longer has any effect on SEO.

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag

Comment: Can you summarise here? If the link breaks there is only the claim left.

Comment: The question only mentions Google Search, but does this cover [Bing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bing) and [DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo) as well?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://juniortoexpert.com/en/should-you-use-meta-keywords-tag/#meta-keywords-tag-support-of-other-search-engines-except-google Like Google, the Bing search engine does not support the meta keywords tag. Yandex and Baidu support this tag, but that may change in the future.